# Is mongoreplay included in the toolset with mongodb 4.0 community version for windows?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0

Where to find mongoreplay tool in mongodb 4.0 community version for windows? It is not in the same place as other tools - mongoexport, mongoimport, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mongoreplay` is currently not included in the Windows installation packages (as at MongoDB 4.0). This tool uses the [`libpcap` packet capture library](https://wiki.wireshark.org/libpcap) which is available on most UNIX/Linux platforms but is not standard on Windows.

There's a relevant feature request to watch/upvote in the MongoDB Jira issue tracker: [TOOLS-1730: Release  mongoreplay for windows](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1730).

I also raised [DOCS-12355](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-12355) as this should be more clearly noted in the documentation.

Comment: Nice explanation with Mongo jira tracking . +1 for libpcap.